# document set routing limit 50mb

Tags: document-set

Hi does anyone know if the hotfix that was supposed to fix the doc set 50mb limit actually works. I downloaded and installed the fix but it still doesn't fix the issue. Just wondering if there was something I need to do apart from install the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the hotfix only solves half the problem. You may also need to make updates to the we.b config to increase the maximum request length:

```
<location path=”OfficialFile.asmx”>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength=”2097151″ executionTimeout=”240″ />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

and configure maximum file size in Central administration –> Manage Web Applications –> Select the Web Application –> General Settings –> Maximum Upload Size
([Source](http://danmyhre.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/50mb-limit-on-files-sent-to-content-organizerofficialfile-asmx/))

Comment: I had already made these configuration changes as I came across the same reference you specified which is why I figured there might be some additional configuration that needs changing. Could it be an ISS timeout that needs to be increased. Although looking at the message I get it clearly says you cannot send a 50mb or greater file so it's probably not an ISS issue.

Comment: Problem solved. I neglected to change the upload limit in the source site. Instead I made the change in the Record Centre. Interestingly enough no matter what the limit is set to. SP will always report the 50mb error message. I did some experiments including setting the upload limit to 2gb. I realize this is not a good idea I just wanted to see what would happen. It failed but I didn't get the 50mb limit this time which suggests there is another limitation being hit. Anyway it doesn't matter because none of our users will be given the pleasure of uploading 2gb files.